# pxssh connecting to an ssh proxy; Timeout exceeded in read_nonblocking()

Tags: python

So I have tried a couple of modules both pxssh, pexpect, etc and I can't seem to get an ssh connection to our ssh proxy to work. Basically what I am wanting to do, is use our SSH proxy, which has access to the rest of our devices as a jumping point to the other devices, then run a command. This works in ipython, however when it connects it raises the exception listed below, however it continue with the rest of the commands and works fine. However when just ran as a python script it just causes the script to fail. I would assume it's failing because of the exception. Is there a way to turn off the exception, or keep it from bailing out? Or am I doing this all wrong?

I have also tried messing with the prompt settings and auto_prompt_reset settings...

The proxy host isn't a true linux host, or cisco for that matter, which is probably why the defaulting settings don't work.

Not really sure where to go from here, so any help or insight would be great.

```
import pxssh
s = pxssh.pxssh()
hostname = '10.10.10.4'
username = 'username'
password = 'password!'
s.login (hostname, username, password)
s.sendline ('connect 10.10.5.1')  
s.prompt(timeout=2)      
print s.before   
s.endline ('')
s.sendline ('show run')
s.prompt(timeout=2)
print s.before
```

Exception that gets posted.

```
In [40]: s.login (hostname, username, password)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TIMEOUT                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-51f00f2075f5> in <module>()
----> 1 s.login (hostname, username, password)

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pxssh.pyc in login(self, server, username, password, terminal_type, original_prompt, login_timeout, port, auto_prompt_reset)
    241             self.close()
    242             raise ExceptionPxssh ('unexpected login response')
--> 243         if not self.synch_original_prompt():
    244             self.close()
    245             raise ExceptionPxssh ('could not synchronize with original prompt')

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pxssh.pyc in synch_original_prompt(self)
    132         # If latency is worse than these values then this will fail.
    133 
--> 134         self.read_nonblocking(size=10000,timeout=1) # GAS: Clear out the cache     before getting the prompt
    135         time.sleep(0.1)
    136         self.sendline()

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect.pyc in read_nonblocking(self, size, timeout)
    822                 raise EOF ('End of File (EOF) in read_nonblocking(). Very pokey     platform.')
    823             else:
--> 824                 raise TIMEOUT ('Timeout exceeded in read_nonblocking().')
    825 
    826         if self.child_fd in r:

TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded in read_nonblocking().
```

Answer (score 4):

After researching this for myself, I came across another article on Stackoverflow in which the asker posted their solution. I tested the solution, and it worked for myself as well. The issue is an out of date / absent snippet of code in usr/lib/python.2.6/dist-packages/pxssh.py. (it may also be in usr/lib/python.2.6/site-packages/pxssh.py).

Navigate to this file and add the following lines of code:

```
self.sendline() #Line 134
time.sleep(0.5) #Line 135
```

This should be inserted just above the line

```
self.read_nonblocking(size=10000,timeout=1) # GAS: Clear out the cache before getting the prompt
```

and viola, run your code again and it should work like a charm.
Credit to: [python pexpect: SSHing then updating the date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911290/python-pexpect-sshing-then-updating-the-date)