# Python Pxssh Timeout exceeded in read_nonblocking()

Tags: python-2.7

I've come here to get back on track about a device on a switch Extreme Network. 
Currently, Extreme Network asks the prompt to say that the switch is not saved. I am currently developing a script to verify if all the switches in the park are protected.

Here's what I start with:

```
s = pxssh.pxssh()
hostname = ('hostname')
username = ('username')
password = ('password')
s.login (hostname, username, password)
```

The only problem is that the last line of my code, I get the following error message:

```
In [93]: s.login (hostname, username, password)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TIMEOUT                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/root/<ipython-input-93-6a124c6a47a0> in <module>()
----> 1 s.login (hostname, username, password)

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pxssh.pyc in login(self, server, username, password,           terminal_type, original_prompt, login_timeout, port, auto_prompt_reset)
241             self.close()
242             raise ExceptionPxssh ('unexpected login response')
--> 243         if not self.synch_original_prompt():
244             self.close()
245             raise ExceptionPxssh ('could not synchronize with original prompt')

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pxssh.pyc in synch_original_prompt(self)
132         # If latency is worse than these values then this will fail.

133 
--> 134         self.read_nonblocking(size=10000,timeout=1) # GAS: Clear out the cache before getting the prompt
135         time.sleep(0.1)
136         self.sendline()

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect.pyc in read_nonblocking(self, size, timeout)
822                 raise EOF ('End of File (EOF) in read_nonblocking(). Very pokey platform.')
823             else:
--> 824                 raise TIMEOUT ('Timeout exceeded in read_nonblocking().')
825 
826         if self.child_fd in r:

TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded in read_nonblocking().
```

Have you any idea?

thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pxssh connecting to an ssh proxy; Timeout exceeded in read\_nonblocking()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055943/pxssh-connecting-to-an-ssh-proxy-timeout-exceeded-in-read-nonblocking)