# Capturing output of a subprocess' subprocess

Tags: python, git, subprocess

I am trying to write a python script to automatically delete a tag from github.  My overall goal is to have a script that can push binaries to a dev release.  If the release exists already, I can delete it through the github API.  However, making a release also makes a tag, and I need to delete that tag before making a new release.  If the tag is not deleted before remaking the release, the release will be listed under the wrong commit, because it will be assigned to the existing tag.

I know that I can delete a tag by running `git push --delete origin :tagname` as a subprocess.  However, I need to pass it a username+password or authorization key in order to do so.  This was my attempt to do so.

```
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['git','push','--delete','origin',tag_name],
                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    proc.communicate(access_token()+'\n\n')
```

However, this fails because while it captures the output of `git`, it does not capture the output of `git-remote-https` which is launched by git, and so I can't supply the access token.  Is there a way to communicate with the subprocess of a subprocess so that I can provide the login details to git?

Comment: I suspect you need to arrange for a pty.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/15911290/1256452 and/or http://stackoverflow.com/a/20128598/1256452

Comment: password/password prompt may be [read/written from/to terminal directly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20980965/4279) without going through the pipe. As @torek said, you could [allocate pseudo-TTY to capture such output](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12471855/4279)

Comment: I'd recommend adding a ssh key to the github account in question and either not use a password (keep the key save then!) or unlock it prior to running the script (using a ssh agent) or unlock it in the script (again using an ssh agent)